# dismissModalView vs popModalView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, viewcontroller

What is the difference between dismissModalViewController and popViewController? In what situations would one work better than the other?

Answer (score 2):

`-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` is the counterpart to `-presentModalViewController:animated:`; `-popViewControllerAnimated:` corresponds to `-pushViewController:animated:`. The former can be called on any view controller, while the latter is a method specifically of `UINavigationController`; both `-presentModalViewController:animated:` and `-pushViewController:animated:`, however, will accept any view controller as their first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When using a UINavigationController you should use popViewController.

When not using a UINavigationController use dismissViewController, as popViewController won't work.